# Overrideing hardcoded element style inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I have no access to the html for this form, all theming has to be done via css that is loaded into the iframe which displays the form. Yes, this code is annoying and bad practice, but it is what it is.

```
<input 
    class="give-input required" 
    type="text" 
    name="give_first" 
    autocomplete="given-name" 
    placeholder="First Name" 
    id="give-first" 
    value="" 
    required="" 
    aria-required="true" 
    style="padding-left: 33px!important;" tabindex="1">
```

Versions of the below, beginning with #give-first and adding greater specificity, do not work

```
#give-first-name-wrap input#give-first.give-input.required[style] 
{ 
    padding-left:0; 
}
```

I don't have a hook to load jQuery into the iframe, very annoyingly!

All suggestions gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

`style` attributes have higher specificity than any selector.

They can only be overridden if they aren't `!important` and you use an `!important` rule.

In this case, the rule is `!important` so you can't override it.

---

You could replace it with JS. You [don't need jQuery](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/).

Comment: Well aware that !important is the issue. If you have a suggestion for a hook I could use to load JS inside the iframe, I would love to hear it.

Comment: I know nothing about how you can interact with the iframe beyond that you can load CSS but can't load jQuery. That's the only information you've provided.

Comment: CSS cannot be written to target HTML elements inside an iframe, only the iframe itself. This is due to cross-domain resource restrictions.